# Is it true a matrix $A$ has determinant $0$ if and only if $A^N=0$?

Tags: matrices

I know that the determinant doesn't stay the same for a matrix $A$ for which the determinant $\neq 0$. I just calculated some determinants of a $3\times 3$ matrix to find that out.

But I also calculated another matrix $A$ for which the determinant is zero, and then I calculated the determinant of $A^2$ and $A^3$ which were also zero.

Is this a theorem?

Comment: Hint: $\det (A*B) = \det (A) * \det (B)$ for square matrices.

Comment: If, but not only if.

Comment: The question asked doesn't match the question in the title.

Answer (score 7):

For a square matrix $A$, and any natural number $n$,
$$\det(A^n) = (\det(A))^n$$
Therefore if $\det(A)=0$, then $\det(A^n)$ will be $0^n=0$. And conversely, if $\det(A^n)=0$, then $\det(A)$ is a scalar $x$ satisfying $x^n=0$, and if you have a matrix over an integral domain (such as $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{C}$) the only solution to $x^n=0$ is $x=0$, so $\det(A)=0$.